# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: favorite1 (code 1)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

An error came up when I debugging my app, I can't really find what have I done wrong, I really don't know why there is a 1 behind favorite, hopefully someone can give me a hint, thanks.
LogCat:

> 02-13 07:42:49.070    1331-1331/me.knoxc.fdemo E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column: favorite1
>   02-13 07:42:49.082    1331-1331/me.knoxc.fdemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: favorite1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entries WHERE isread IS NULL), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entries WHERE favorite1) FROM entries JOIN (SELECT _id AS joined_feed_id, name, url, icon, groupid FROM feeds) AS f ON (entries.feedid = f.joined_feed_id)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
>               at me.knoxc.fdemo.provider.FeedDataContentProvider.query(FeedDataContentProvider.java:269)
>               at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:744)
>               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:199)
>               at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:414)
>               at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:357)
>               at me.knoxc.fdemo.adapter.DrawerAdapter.updateNumbers(DrawerAdapter.java:208)
>               at me.knoxc.fdemo.adapter.DrawerAdapter.(DrawerAdapter.java:60)
>               at me.knoxc.fdemo.activity.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:331)
>               at me.knoxc.fdemo.activity.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:39)
>               at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:483)
>               at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:451)
>               at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:144)
>               at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:110)
>               at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:43)
>               at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:256)
>               at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:91)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Key code of FeedDataContentProvider.java

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    int matchCode = URI_MATCHER.match(uri);

    if ((matchCode == URI_FEEDS || matchCode == URI_GROUPS || matchCode == URI_FEEDS_FOR_GROUPS) && sortOrder == null) {
        sortOrder = FeedData.FeedColumns.PRIORITY;
    }

    switch (matchCode) {
        case URI_GROUPED_FEEDS: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.FEEDS_TABLE_WITH_GROUP_PRIORITY);
            sortOrder = "IFNULL(group_priority, " + FeedData.FeedColumns.PRIORITY + "), IFNULL(" + FeedData.FeedColumns.GROUP_ID + ", " + FeedData.FeedColumns._ID + "), " + FeedData.FeedColumns.IS_GROUP + " DESC, " + FeedData.FeedColumns.PRIORITY;
            break;
        }
        case URI_GROUPS: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.FeedColumns.TABLE_NAME);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.FeedColumns.IS_GROUP).append(Constants.DB_IS_TRUE).append(Constants.DB_OR)
                    .append(FeedData.FeedColumns.GROUP_ID).append(Constants.DB_IS_NULL));
            break;
        }
        case URI_FEEDS_FOR_GROUPS: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.FeedColumns.TABLE_NAME);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.FeedColumns.GROUP_ID).append('=').append(uri.getPathSegments().get(1)));
            break;
        }
        case URI_GROUP:
        case URI_FEED: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.FeedColumns.TABLE_NAME);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.FeedColumns._ID).append('=').append(uri.getPathSegments().get(1)));
            break;
        }
        case URI_FEEDS: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.FeedColumns.TABLE_NAME);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.FeedColumns.IS_GROUP).append(Constants.DB_IS_NULL));
            break;
        }
        case URI_FILTERS: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.FilterColumns.TABLE_NAME);
            break;
        }
        case URI_FILTERS_FOR_FEED: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.FilterColumns.TABLE_NAME);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.FilterColumns.FEED_ID).append('=').append(uri.getPathSegments().get(1)));
            break;
        }
        case URI_ENTRY_FOR_FEED:
        case URI_ENTRY_FOR_GROUP:
        case URI_SEARCH_ENTRY: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.ENTRIES_TABLE_WITH_FEED_INFO);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.EntryColumns._ID).append('=').append(uri.getPathSegments().get(3)));
            break;
        }
        case URI_ENTRIES_FOR_FEED: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.ENTRIES_TABLE_WITH_FEED_INFO);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.EntryColumns.FEED_ID).append('=').append(uri.getPathSegments().get(1)));
            break;
        }
        case URI_ENTRIES_FOR_GROUP: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.ENTRIES_TABLE_WITH_FEED_INFO);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.FeedColumns.GROUP_ID).append('=').append(uri.getPathSegments().get(1)));
            break;
        }
        case URI_ALL_ENTRIES:
        case URI_ENTRIES: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.ENTRIES_TABLE_WITH_FEED_INFO);
            break;
        }
        case URI_SEARCH: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.ENTRIES_TABLE_WITH_FEED_INFO);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(getSearchWhereClause(uri.getPathSegments().get(2)));
            break;
        }
        case URI_FAVORITES_ENTRY:
        case URI_ALL_ENTRIES_ENTRY:
        case URI_ENTRY: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.ENTRIES_TABLE_WITH_FEED_INFO);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.EntryColumns._ID).append('=').append(uri.getPathSegments().get(1)));
            break;
        }
        case URI_FAVORITES: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.ENTRIES_TABLE_WITH_FEED_INFO);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.EntryColumns.IS_FAVORITE).append(Constants.DB_IS_TRUE));
            break;
        }
        case URI_TASKS: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.TaskColumns.TABLE_NAME);
            break;
        }
        case URI_TASK: {
            queryBuilder.setTables(FeedData.TaskColumns.TABLE_NAME);
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.EntryColumns._ID).append('=').append(uri.getPathSegments().get(1)));
            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal query. Match code=" + matchCode + "; uri=" + uri);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase database = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(database, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}<br>
```

Key code of FeedData.java

```
public static class EntryColumns implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entries";

    public static final String FEED_ID = "feedid";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String ABSTRACT = "abstract";
    public static final String MOBILIZED_HTML = "mobilized";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String FETCH_DATE = "fetch_date";
    public static final String IS_READ = "isread";
    public static final String LINK = "link";
    public static final String IS_FAVORITE = "favorite";
    public static final String ENCLOSURE = "enclosure";
    public static final String GUID = "guid";
    public static final String AUTHOR = "author";
    public static final String IMAGE_URL = "image_url";
    public static final String[] PROJECTION_ID = new String[]{EntryColumns._ID};
    public static final String WHERE_READ = EntryColumns.IS_READ + Constants.DB_IS_TRUE;
    public static final String WHERE_UNREAD = "(" + EntryColumns.IS_READ + Constants.DB_IS_NULL + Constants.DB_OR + EntryColumns.IS_READ + Constants.DB_IS_FALSE + ')';
    public static final String[][] COLUMNS = new String[][]{{_ID, TYPE_PRIMARY_KEY}, {FEED_ID, TYPE_EXTERNAL_ID}, {TITLE, TYPE_TEXT},
            {ABSTRACT, TYPE_TEXT}, {MOBILIZED_HTML, TYPE_TEXT}, {DATE, TYPE_DATE_TIME}, {FETCH_DATE, TYPE_DATE_TIME}, {IS_READ, TYPE_BOOLEAN}, {LINK, TYPE_TEXT},
            {IS_FAVORITE, TYPE_BOOLEAN}, {ENCLOSURE, TYPE_TEXT}, {GUID, TYPE_TEXT}, {AUTHOR, TYPE_TEXT}, {IMAGE_URL, TYPE_TEXT}};
    public static final String WHERE_NOT_FAVORITE = "(" + EntryColumns.IS_FAVORITE + Constants.DB_IS_NULL + Constants.DB_OR + EntryColumns.IS_FAVORITE + Constants.DB_IS_FALSE + ')';

    public static Uri ENTRIES_FOR_FEED_CONTENT_URI(String feedId) {
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/feeds/" + feedId + "/entries");
    }

    public static Uri ENTRIES_FOR_FEED_CONTENT_URI(long feedId) {
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/feeds/" + feedId + "/entries");
    }

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/entries");

    public static Uri ENTRIES_FOR_GROUP_CONTENT_URI(String groupId) {
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/groups/" + groupId + "/entries");
    }

    public static Uri ENTRIES_FOR_GROUP_CONTENT_URI(long groupId) {
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/groups/" + groupId + "/entries");
    }

    public static Uri ALL_ENTRIES_CONTENT_URI(String entryId) {
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/all_entries/" + entryId);
    }

    public static final Uri ALL_ENTRIES_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/all_entries");

    public static Uri CONTENT_URI(String entryId) {
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/entries/" + entryId);
    }

    public static Uri CONTENT_URI(long entryId) {
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/entries/" + entryId);
    }

    public static Uri PARENT_URI(String path) {
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/')));
    }

    public static final Uri FAVORITES_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/favorites");

    public static Uri SEARCH_URI(String search) {
        return Uri.parse(CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/entries/search/" + (TextUtils.isEmpty(search) ? " " : Uri.encode(search))); // The space is mandatory here with empty search
    }


}
```

Comment: what is in line is 269 in FeedDataContentProvider.java ?

Comment: Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(database, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

Comment: why You are appending this to IS_FAVORITE : append(Constants.DB_IS_TRUE) ?

Comment: I want to check that the IS_FAVORITE column is null or not in the entries table, it have to be done when opening the app for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is the culprit:

```
case URI_FAVORITES: {
         // .....
         queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.EntryColumns.IS_FAVORITE).append(Constants.DB_IS_TRUE));
         break;
}
```

What is `Constants.DB_IS_TRUE` equal to?

Whatever it is equal, in this case "1" I assume, it gets appended to the "favorite" column name, and results in "favorite1".

Comment: Yes, you are right, DB_IS_TRUE = "1", but why it become the wrong sentence, or there is another way to let IS_FAVORITE equals TRUE, (FeedData.EntryColumns.IS_FAVORITE).equals(Constants.DB_IS_TRUE)?

Answer (score 0):

```
case URI_FAVORITES: {
     // .....
     queryBuilder.appendWhere(new StringBuilder(FeedData.EntryColumns.IS_FAVORITE)

.append("=") //add this line

.append(Constants.DB_IS_TRUE));
     break;
}
```

Comment: I have added the words like you said, but the error still there, and I also added .append("=") to the place that I need to use DB_IS_TRUE.